# Get Response from Java Server on android device

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I am send a request to a Java server from android phone and it is received on server side but unable to get response on the phone
Not sure why unable to get response

Below is my code

```
private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    private final String message;

    ClientThread(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port number on the named host.
            client = new Socket("192.168.0.88", 8094);  // connect to server
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            printwriter.write(message);  // write the message to output stream
            Log.d("server request", message);
            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        // Read Server Response
                        Log.d("server response", line);
                    
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            // closing the connection
            client.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `printwriter.close();` Dont do that as it will close the socket too.

Comment: And do not use runOnUiThread to read from the stream. All internet code should be done in a thread. And you are already in a thread..

Comment: Further you should tell what exactly the server is sending.

Comment: the server is sending a string as acknowledgment

Comment: But a string is not alway a line and you use readLine() so let the server send a line. And why didnt you adapt your code already?

Comment: if printwriter.close() is removed, the server does not receive the request

Comment: I think that is also a string/line issue. Sadly you dud not react on string/line.

Comment: I am not sure about the string/line. But they solution I provide seemed to do the trick with some modifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go a solution to the issue. Needed to open my input stream before sending request to server

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        private final String message;

        ClientThread(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String fromServer;
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.2", 8094);
                Log.d("server connect", "Connected!");
                boolean run = true;

                while (run) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(message);
                    fromServer = in.readLine();
                    Log.d("server resp", "received2: " + fromServer);
                    if (fromServer.equals("olleH")) {
                        out.println("Bye");
                    }
                    socket.close();
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }

            } catch (
                    IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Needed to open my input stream before sending request to server...*    I'm not exactly sure what that means but it sounds incorrect. Also, the code in the `while(run){` appears to be an infinite loop. And since closing the inputstream or outputstream of the socket also closes the socket it doesn't make sense to have that code in a loop.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions they make sense